# Multiple Internet Connection

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-connection, dual-channel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I combine two LANs into one to get double speed?](https://superuser.com/questions/240122/can-i-combine-two-lans-into-one-to-get-double-speed)

I have a similar situation as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/103572/dual-internet-connection-setup) question. But I'm using Windows 7 32-bit on my laptop.

I have a 128 kbps DSL connection and another GPRS connection from mobile to PC via USB cable.

How can I use both connections to improve my speed? Or is it possible to use them on different browsers? Like one for IE and one for Chrome. If it is not possible then, it's alright if I  at least get an improved combined speed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use two internet connections for either of the things you want to do. You will have to use one or the other because the computer has no way of determining which to use for each browser, nor can it split the connection between the two for improved speed.

Short answer: You can't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks very much for correcting my English. :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Ismail. ^^