# connected ethernet without disabling wireless, now I have *two* LAN ip's?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If a computer is connected to internet via wireless and lan both, which way Internet traffic would flow?](https://superuser.com/questions/102742/if-a-computer-is-connected-to-internet-via-wireless-and-lan-both-which-way-inte)

Ok I'm on ubuntu 11.04, not too knowledgeable about network stuff. Usually people ask things like "wired works but wireless does not!". In m y case, I'm just curious about what it means to have *both* of them seemingly connected.

In 'ipconfig' in shell I see that I have 192.168.1.2 for the wireless AND 192.168.1.3 for the ethernet. What does this mean for applications, does one of the two get precedence? It seems like my pages load slightly faster, so perhaps the ethernet is being used, but I could be imagining the speedup...

By the way, both IP's are from the same router, if that wasn't clear...

Comment: No big deal in there I guess : you are using your two NIC (network interface cards), so you get one LAN IP  by NIC probably from your DHCP service provider. I see no particular reason why this would speed up your connection, but for sure one of both interfaces is faster than the other one (theoritically the wired one).

Comment: It's certainly not an 'exact duplicate' guys; the link posted largely has answers like "it depends on your OS!" but the original poster didn't state their OS. I would think that a more precise answer for my OS / version is possible. 

In contrast, I've tried this in windows XP long ago and it basically fails- that's why I'm scratching my head now!

Comment: You may google "linux set up priority multiple network interfaces" and find some links like this one : http://natisbad.org/dyn-net/index.html, as your question is not accurate enough to get a straight answer.